# Unable to Proxy to Websocket via Nginx inside a VM

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, django-channels

I am working with nginx and django channels. The Django app has an Http connection and a WebSocket connection. The diagram below shows the three scenarios and how they work.

Situation 1 - Everything is setup locally and the client can send http requests and create a websocket connection to the django app.

Situation 2 - Only the django app is setup on the VM and the client can send http requests and create a websocket connection to the django app.

Situation 3 - Everything is setup in a VM (VirtualBox) and the client can send http requests and CANNOT create a websocket connection to the django app. The django app responds with a 404 error for the websocket connection attempt.

[image]

This is the nginx config

Note: The Django app is being run in a docker container, which is called 'backend'.

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    upstream backend {
        server backend:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /backend/ {
            proxy_pass         http://backend;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /static/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend/static;
        }
    }
}
```

The logs for the django app show the http request being successful. Then a failed GET request at the websocket endpoint.

> WARNING Not Found: /backend/ws/processor
>
> "GET /backend/ws/processor/"
> 404 3127

So it appears that nginx is redirecting the request, but it is not being upgraded for a websocket connection as per the configuration. The configuration does work locally under the same setup conditions.  However, i am able to connect directly to the django app via the VM from the client (Situation 2).

The proxy works locally and does redirect the http connections correctly when inside the VM. The ports 8000 and 80 are both forwarded on the VM.

This leads me to believe that the nginx configuration is incorrect is not able to upgrade the request for the web socket connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the proxy_http_version appears to fix this issue.

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    upstream backend {
        server backend:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /backend/ {
            proxy_pass         http://backend;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;   <===== ADD THIS LINE
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /static/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend/static;
        }
    }
}
```